# Stuck On Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Here is the problem in the terminal:

```
    treehouse:~/projects/odot (master *) $ bin/rails generate model todo_item todo_list:references content:string -p
/home/treehouse/projects/odot/config/application.rb:23:in `<class:Application>': undefined method `configure' for RSpec:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /home/treehouse/projects/odot/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Odot>'
    from /home/treehouse/projects/odot/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `require'
    from /home/treehouse/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Here is the odot/config/application.rb file:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)

module Odot
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    RSpec.configure do |c|
        c.expose_current_running_example_as :example
    end

    RSpec.configure do |c|
        c.expose_current_running_example_as :example
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the bin/rails file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

I do not know how to access the .rbenv/.... files.

I can't seem to wrap my head around what's wrong. These are default files that were in the folder when starting my rails todo list application. I did several rspec tests in three different files and after finishing the last one this occurred at it won't let me proceed with any other tasks.

This keeps ongoing on when running bin/rake:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `configure' for RSpec:Module
/home/treehouse/projects/odot/config/application.rb:23:in `<class:Application>'
/home/treehouse/projects/odot/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Odot>'
/home/treehouse/projects/odot/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/treehouse/projects/odot/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/treehouse/projects/odot/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

Then here is the rakefile file:

```
# Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
# for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

Odot::Application.load_tasks
```

I have no clue what's going on. Any luck? Cheers.

Comment: If it was previously working, then it might be possible that your rbenv has changed.

Comment: You might be right. I was running into some errors while creating a spec test that I hit bundle update if that would resolved something. Turns out I forgot to include a "do" in one of my rspec tests. I do not think that would be the case though. I am unsure whether I had a different version of rake or not. I do not recall nor can figure out what could have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put RSpec configuration in `application.rb`. `application.rb` is for core configuration of the rails app which applies to all environments. You use it to setup stuff like timezones and which middleware you want to use in your rails stack.

RSpec should be placed in the test group of your Gemfile so that it is not loaded when not needed - IE in production.

```
gem 'something'

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

There is also one really important part of `application.rb`:

```
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)
```

Which tells Bundler to load all the gems in the default group and the current "environment group" (development, test or production). So if you start your server in production it will blow up on the line `RSpec.configure` since the RSpec gem has not been required (nor should it be).

The correct place for Rspec configuration is `spec/spec_helper.rb` or `spec/rails_helper.rb`.